# Inherit user control designer

Tags: c#, winforms

If I want to extend a standard user control, currently I do it like this:

**Edit 3: Code moved to bottom**

The problem is that I can't add these buttons through the designer. But if I add a user control and not a class I can add it via the designer, but then of cause it is not a button. So I would have to completely define my own button and I cannot simply expand the existing one. If I change the inheritance from UserControl to Button, it is again not possible.

So how can I extend a control and also "inherit" the designer so that this control can also be added via the designer?

**Edit:**
This is the error I always get:

[image]

P.S.: Of cause I built the project before trying to add them.

**Edit 3 @Jimi asked for:**

NoFucusCueButton.cs

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FoeTools.Controls {
    /// <summary>
    /// Modified button which has no focus rectangles when focused and the window changes.
    /// </summary>
    public class NoFocusCueBotton : Button {
        protected override bool ShowFocusCues => false;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new instance of a <see cref="NoFocusCueBotton"/>
        /// </summary>
        public NoFocusCueBotton() { }
    }
}
```

BringToFrontButton.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FoeTools.Controls {
    /// <summary>
    /// Button which brings a given target control to front when the button was clicked.
    /// </summary>
    public class BringToFrontButton : NoFocusCueBotton {
        /// <summary>
        /// The target control which should be brought to front.
        /// </summary>
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        [Browsable(true)]
        [DefaultValue(null)]
        [Category("Behavior")]
        [Description("The target this button should bring to front.")]
        public Control Target { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new instance of a <see cref="BringToFrontButton"/>
        /// </summary>
        public BringToFrontButton() { }

        protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e) {
            Target.BringToFront();
            base.OnClick(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The project structure is very simple because the project just started:

[image]

Comment: Why can't you add your Custom Controls to a Form/Container in the Designer? What is the problem? You don't need a custom designer to add a Button to a Container control. Just drop it from the ToolBox.

Comment: Pls look at edit

Comment: Add a public parameter-less Constructor to the base class, remove that event subscription from the Constructor of the derived class and override `OnClick` instead, then write `Target?.BringToFront();` there (note the Elvis).

Comment: Edited. Sure I forgot the null check. New version... same error

Comment: Have you rebuilt the Project after those changes?

Comment: Sure. Look at the P.S. :) I tried Build, Rebuild, Clean+Rebuild, and nothing works

Comment: Well, post the complete class definition, including `using` section, the `namespace` and a description of their *placement* (where the classes are defined and what is the relation with the main Project. I.e., if these classes are part of a secondary Project, if it's a class Library etc. Try also to just copy/paste these two classes in a new file into a clean (new, empty) Project and see what happens. There's no practical reason why it should not work in *normal* conditions.

Comment: Edit3 is done. When necessary information is missing just ask.

Comment: Add `[ToolboxItem(true)]` on top of both the classes. Clean/Rebuild the Solution (not the Project). Run it. Try again. You didn't say what happens if you add these two classes to a clean Project.

Comment: ``[ToolboxItem(defaultType: true)]`` does not work.... But ``[ToolboxItem(typeof(NoFocusCueBotton))]`` does. But why? Why is this attribute needed? Where is the difference? @Jimi Thanks a lot. You saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: The nested namespace.